# intellij 2019.02 failed to run any scala class due to multiple scala lib version

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

In my build.sbt the scala version is "2.11.12"
and Intellij version is 2019.2 community edition

[image]

and class path also having the same scala jar's version

[image]

When I running a scala class I got below error.

Error:scalac: Multiple 'scala-library*.jar' files (scala-library-2.11.12.jar, scala-library-2.11.12.jar) in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK sbt: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12:jar

I tried with multiple options to solve a problem
1.removed scala jars from class path
2. reimport project again
3. invalidate catch

still wont work any option

Comment: Same issue occurs with 2.12.9 with even simplest possible `build.sbt` .

Comment: Check the dependencies, and avoid forcing Scala version the Scala deps

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have duplicate entry in one of the xml files in you .idea directory. You could search for it and delete extra entry, or just delete whole .idea directory and re-import your project

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, getting issue because there are two scala JDK  1. at project level 2. default at IntelliJ level

By default, the IntelliJ Scala compiler server is also available when running the scala classes.

Previously it was selected Now I just deselected (shown in below screen shot)and click on ok and then ran the classes and it works perfectly.

[image]